# C: Assignment invalid: lvalue is READ ONLY using strtok

Tags: c, strtok

I have problems when using strtok. I want token to has a reserved size so its contents doesn't corrupt other data (I have small memory, because I'm working over a MCU, not a PC). Then I decided to declare ir as an array with a declared size.

But then I have this error: Assignment invalid: lvalue is READ ONLY

```
#DEFINE BUFFER_SIZE 128
static int8 buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]; // Declared as global

void myFunction(){
   char separador[3],  token[BUFFER_SIZE], cmd[BUFFER_SIZE];
   strcpy(cmd, buffer); // buffer is a global variable declared ad
   strcpy(separador, ",;"); 
   token = strtok(cmd, separador); // <----- ERROR
   //...
}
```

What does that error exactly mean? Is it because I haven't initialised the array? If I declare it as static, would it work?

Comment: There are many examples of using `strtok` all over the Internet. Check those, and maybe read a little on the differences of pointers and arrays in C (which, I'll admit, are very small.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtok` returns bits of `cmd`, so you don't allocate storage for it's return value. You just want token to be a `char*`:

```
char* token;
```

Comment: I just gave for grant that token was storing the characters, not only the bits. I thought of it as in JAVA, where I do think it is like that, if I am not also wrong. Should have read the C reference carefully, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should declare

```
char token[BUFFER_SIZE]
```

as

```
char *token
```

because it gets an adress assigned within the memory allocated for `cmd[BUFFER_SIZE]`
tokens adress cannot be reassiged (In the way you declared it).

Answer (score 0):

`token` is the name of array. it ls a constant and cannot be left value. I think you need `char *`.